# @discordjs/opus fatal error C1083 while installing

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js, npm-install, opus

So I am trying to get opus for my discord bot so he could play music, but instead it returns something like this:

https://justpaste.it/3t3wi

I'm kind of new to installing libraries, npm and such so I would really appreaciate any positive feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest you to try this compound `opusscript` and `discord.js`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/opusscript